# Interface Builder Compiler Error 255 - Opened project in Xcode 6 then went back to Xcode 5 and now this is happening

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, xcode6

I'm getting this error and my app won't compile:

```
CompileStoryboard AApp/Base.lproj/Main_iPhone.storyboard
cd /Users/A.Frizalone/Downloads/AApp
setenv IBSC_MINIMUM_COMPATIBILITY_VERSION 7.0
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode 3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode 3.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
setenv XCODE_DEVELOPER_USR_PATH "/Applications/Xcode 3.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/.."
/Applications/Xcode\ 3.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool --errors --warnings --notices --minimum-deployment-target 7.0 --output-format human-readable-text --compile /Users/A.Frizalone/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ATesting-aqsokppxqbwcrbgvpgiljaexuqha/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/AirFastTicketsTesting.app/Base.lproj/Main_iPhone.storyboardc /Users/A.Frizalone/Downloads/AApp/AApp/Base.lproj/Main_iPhone.storyboard
```

Answer (score 0):

Found solution: I cleaned my project (Product > Clean) and it works fine now.